# Wordpress Woocommerce product list images do not resize

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, image-scaling

I got some problems with my WooCommerce site, whereas the images on the products list does not work

http://bio7.dk.linux82.curanetserver.dk/billede/

This is the link... as you can see, the images are not all the same size, even though all images are set to be

```
210pixels X 210 pixels with Hard-Crop
```

I hope anyone can tell me, why the images aren't that size...

My Thanks.

Comment: Did you regenerated your thumbnails? In other words did you re-uploaded the images? Also show us your `add_image_size` function.

Comment: I dont know what the `add_image_size` is?

Comment: Than what do you mean by this _210pixels X 210 pixels with Hard-Crop_

Comment: Never mind, solved the probme ;)
I just had to renerate the thumbnails as you said :)
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Because of the size of the boxes, once you change the size of the boxes the size of the picture will change as well